# AWS API Gateway to send the data to Kinesis Stream from HTTP URL as a Source

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

I am new to API Gateway and as per my requirement I want to send json formatted data to Kinesis from HTTP URL.

However I have created a REST API and created a GET method with HTTP Integration.

But now I want to upload this data which I have collected from HTTP URL to Kinesis and I am not able to find any way to upload this data to Kinesis.

Answer (score 3):

API gateway nicely integrates with kinesis via what is known as a 'Proxy Integration'. In this case the rest call will place the data onto a kinesis stream.

AWS have a great example of how do to this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html

Key Points:

1. Create a new rest API via API Gateway
2. Check the proxy integration box
3. Select the desired kinesis data stream
4. insure correct IAM permissions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @Johnny Chivers for your response. This I know how to create API Gateway to upload data into Kinesis Stream. But I am stuck on how to provide external HTTP URL as a source to Kinesis, so that API Gateway will take the data from external HTTP URL as a source and then upload this data to Kinesis Stream. Data which I am getting from external HTTP URL is in JSON format.

Comment: Really depends on your exact use case. If you are invoking the external URL? You could do this from an aws lambda function and then use the Boto3 library (if using python3) to place this returned json object onto the stream. It's fairly straight forward.

If you need to invoke this external URL from the webpage it's self? Then you need to pass the retuned json object into your APIgateway endpoint somewhere in your source code on the webpage.